# Media query looks way different on Browser than Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Im porting a layout using this query:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 640px)
```

This is the url:  http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/adc/prototype/html/

I was working only with the resized browser to begin with. but when I tried to check on mobile devices (iphone 4, 5, ipod 4 and galaxy S2), was drastically different, awfully different.

So I've started working focusing on the mobile view (it is a webview, so browse resizing its not a concern), but when I tried to view it from Galaxy S3, the result was pretty much the same from the browser (awful).

I know S3 is acting the way it should be (as far as i know), since its the same way as the browser, but what about the other devices, what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: Looking at the link on Galaxy S2 seems to work as expected. Content is a bit too large for the screen so some parts are cut off but otherwise works ok.

Comment: I see you have added the meta tags form my question so maybe that fixed the issue as I only tested on mobile device after posting the answer :)

Comment: @DominicM, I've added the tags since a big while right now.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices often scale content to fit the screen, you need to tell the device that the site is mobile friendly and not to scale pixels.

Add this in the head of your html file:

```
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This should work for most android devices, iPhone may or may not need different meta tags.

Comment: Are you sure `maximum-scale=1.0;` is a good idea? Wouldn't it prevent zooming into the page?

Comment: I just tested on Galaxy S2 and yes you can't zoom in but the scaling renders any media queries useless so it's a fair trade off I think. I am not aware of another way to prevent scaling. Also if you use responsive design you don't really need zoom as the site should fit the device perfectly if it's done right making zoom quite useless as there is no quality or extra detail to gain by zooming.

Comment: Good to hear, please accept the answer if it solved you problem.

Comment: As I posted earlier, I was using it already. Still got the same problem.

Comment: Ah. In some cases zooming may be required (viewing on tablet or something). Since he doesn't need it it's fine :)

Comment: Well, it seems to work fine on Galaxy S2, what is the issue exactly? For me it looks almost same on chrome browser and galaxy S2.

Comment: @wei2912, with responsive design you shouldn't need to zoom as it will display perfectly on any screen size. It would still be nice to have but I don't know if that's possible with responsive design.

Comment: Should be possible, I recall reading an article about why maximum-scale=1.0; shouldn't be used, but can't find that article. Maybe there's some small images somewhere, maybe the poor reader is visually impaired etc. though, it all depends on your site. In ideal conditions you shouldn't need to zoom :D

Comment: Yeah guys, this specific case there is no need for zoom. there is not too much text at all, so no problems there.

Comment: I looked into it and if you remove "maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" from the code in my answer, the zoom works just fine and no scaling occurs. Useful if you need zoom for other pages :)

Comment: @DominicM, the layout here looks absurdly different on chrome. If you pass to the second screen itself, you will see the tiles all messed up. And its like that on S3 as well, thats my issue. On S2, iphone4 and 5 looks just fine as well. But as I said earlier, browser and S3 looks strange. This bugs me, I don't know which is displaying the "right" visual

Comment: I think it may be simply that S3 has higher res than S2 falling out of your media query rule.Even on S2 it's broken past 1st screen with input fields cut off. I would trust chrome btw.

Comment: As I stated earlier, the S3 is trigerring the query itself. But it is behaving just like chrome is. If i scale down chrome res a bit, it gets more in place like the other resolutions as well. But its still different.

Comment: Well, "different" is not much of a description. It will be different due to different aspect ration anyways. Maybe you should post a screenshot of each otherwise it's impossible to answer.

Comment: http://puu.sh/2cAdm The tiles ratio are fine within this width. But the margin itself breaks for example. while on S2 and other devices I've said before, are lined up perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I compared the screenshot to chrome rendering of the link and it is 100% the same. Every second tile is slightly miss-aligned in chrome like in the screenshot.

Comment: This ss is from chrome. Does it looks like the same on your S2? Because mine looks aligned. So does iphone 4 and 5 here...

Comment: I have chrome so there was no point in posting chrome screenshot. In s2 I see 2 tiles in single row instead of just 1 in chrome but they are cutt off on the right because the page resolution is too high. Rotating S2 shows tiles miss-aligned as well.

Comment: Oh, the S2 rotation is no issue. it will be fixed directly on the webview capsule anyway. This is what im talking about. You see 2 tiles in a single row, while chrome never shows that aspect, even if i change to the same resolution as S2 with window resizer.

Comment: You're gonna have to replicate the issue on jsfiddle because your css file is impossible to troubleshoot. Also you may think about using jquery isotope plugin for layout such as this.

Comment: Yeah, im using SASS on this project. Guess I will just work with another query for a bit larger devices. Thanks for the good discussion here.